# How to correctly populate array of objects in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

On a button click based on value matching, I am trying populate an array with objects that i visualise in another components, here's how i do it:

This is the method that commits the mutation @click:

```
modifySelectedLimitCardStatus() {
  const payload = [
    this.editedLimitCard.id,
    (this.editedLimitCard.limit_card_selected_status = true)
  ];
  this.$store.commit("selectLimitCard", payload);
}
```

The state & mutation:

```
 selectedLimitCard: [],

 selectLimitCard: (state, payload) => {
    state.limitCards.forEach(limitCard => {
      if (
        limitCard.id === payload[0] &&
        limitCard.limit_card_selected_status !== payload[1]
      ) {
        state.selectedLimitCard.push(limitCard);
        console.log(state.selectedLimitCard);
      }
    });
  }
```

And finally, the getter:

```
  getSelectedLimitCard: state => {
    return state.selectedLimitCard;
  }
```

As you can see in the code, i log the state in the mutation and it's populated,

```
[{…}, __ob__: Observer]
```

however, in the component that is supposed to visualise the getter

```
  <v-list :items="getSelectedLimitCard">
    <v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile-content>№</v-list-tile-content>
      <v-list-tile-content class="align-end">
        {{ getSelectedLimitCard.limit_card_number }}
      </v-list-tile-content>
    </v-list-tile>
  </v-list>
```

i get nothing.
Everything was working fine before i introduced the `.push()` way ot populating the array.
Can someone help me out & point out what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide code of `<v-list></v-list>` component?

Comment: @EvilArthas I have edited the post with the requested information, sir!

Comment: Are you using Vuetify?

Comment: Yes, i am using Vuetify.

Comment: `{{ getSelectedLimitCard.limit_card_numbr }}` `getSelectedLimitCard` is type of `Array`, so maybe try accessing the first element `getSelectedLimitCard[0]`

Comment: Are you sure that `<v-list />` has prop named `items`? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#list

Comment: @EvilArthas getSelectedLimitCard[0].id produced the desired result, however the idea is to vusualise dynamic data, so i'll have to avoid the [0] part. Any suggestions with that?

Comment: I can write some code of  `v-list` in answer :)

Comment: @EvilArthas That would be lovely!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196829/discussion-between-pok3r-princ3-and-evilarthas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<v-list>
  <v-list-tile v-for="card in getSelectedLimitCard" :key="card.limit_card_number">
    <v-list-tile-content>№</v-list-tile-content>
    <v-list-tile-content class="align-end">
      {{ card.limit_card_number }}
    </v-list-tile-content>
  </v-list-tile>
</v-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!